# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect with Heroku server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, heroku-cli

I am attempting to access my MongoDB cluster with a NodeJS application that is being deployed on Heroku via GitHub. No matter what I try, this error gets thrown as soon as the application launches:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect

My code that is attempting to access this is the following:

```
//Connect to mongo and create a connection
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const mongoClient = new MongoClient(process.env.connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoClient.connect();
```

I've done a console log to make sure that process.env.connectionString contains my connection string to my Mongo Cluster. I've also made sure that my cluster allows all incoming connections. Is there something else I am missing, or am I completely off-base here?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly leverage Heroku mongolab addon. Export your locally mongodb to the new mongolab db generated by Heroku. It should be pretty straight forward.